# Scroll Bar comes with a big dimension image

Tags: css, image, scroll, centering

I am designing a web page which only contain a image (Images are going to change with time). Dimensions of the images are not fixed. So I planned to show images in both vertically and horizontally center. For horizontal center I use `margin:0 auto;` and for vertical center i use `line-height and vertical-align` as explained in may SO answers. To constrain images which have bigger dimensions then the windows i used `max-height, max-width` property with the image tag.

To see: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knoxxs/EqeTx/7/)  {to see what happening replace the image with any image of greater dimension the browser window. for small images everything works just fine.}

I am also sharing snapshots:

1. With small image:
   [image]
2. With big image:(I hope you can see the little scroll bar in the right)
   [image]

I am using Google Chrome (20.0.1132.17)

Comment: I've constructed an [html file](http://jsfiddle.net/EzbV8/) containing all the css, js and html codes you provided in your jsfiddle, with just changing the image to a  large enough image, and it shows without any scrollbar in my chrome 19.0.1084.52 m version. Could not get to the problem.

Comment: @HeartBeat, Now agian see the fiddle I have provided. I changed the image. Hope you will see the problem

Comment: saw your problem, but don't know why this is happening :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
html, #container /* whatever your container is*/ {
    overflow: none;
}
```

---

EDIT:

You'll have to post a live page with the content you mean. JSFiddle is not enough for this question.

You can set `max-height: 100%`, but then you also have to set

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have used `max-height:100%` and `* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;        
}`               What I am saying is I have used max-height:100%, then why overflow is happening??

Comment: Can you post that page with the large image (the URL)? I'll inspect it, but I cannot just guess what is wrong.

Comment: sry I can't show the live page right now, I don't have any running server right now.  I used this image http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7072/7300743046_05ca0ac2e7_b.jpg  I shared the code and also the snapshot with the inducing scroll bar

Comment: :P, the image only uses half my screen. I'll find another one and test with your code :)

Comment: OK, I have tried it, and I also get a little gap at the bottom. I have removed all padding + margins, it still shows. The only way I have been able to remove it is by setting `float: left;` on the image. This removes the gap. Any other way, I'd just use javascript, or `overflow: none`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11920/discussion-between-knoxxs-and-hidde)